# How to put envers annotations into XML Mapping Metadata(orm.xml) file

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

In my application, I am using XML Mapping Metadata as an alternative to annotation. It worked fine for all the JPA annotations so far. 
However for Auditing, I am using Hibernate Envers. I am declaring
   @Audited
   @AuditTable("LOAN_APPLICANT_AUDIT")
The only problem is how to put these annotations in XML mapping metadata form.
There is a requirement that the user should specify the list of tables, which needs to be audited.
Plus he should be also able to configure the name of AUDIT tables according to his needs.
The last step is that the particular column names inside a table which needs to be audited should be configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that's not possible. Envers works by annotating POJOs only. There is a JIRA ticket to enable XML config, but it doesn't look like that feature will come anytime soon:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3887

Anyway, if you want to use Envers, you'll have to go with annotations.