# How to use Hibernate-Envers without .class files for entities

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers, hbm

In my application I am using hibernate with only hbm files.I don't have .class files for entities.

I have to implement auditing for the entities. Since I don't have .class files, I cannot use @Audited annotation. How to achieve this using hbm files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put envers annotations into XML Mapping Metadata(orm.xml) file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781057/how-to-put-envers-annotations-into-xml-mapping-metadataorm-xml-file)

Comment: Ya, thanks for the update!