# Add Envers for LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a spring hibernate application where I use hibernate-xml based mapping instead of annotations. In detail I use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to register my mapping resource files:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">           
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/resources/MyObject.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Now I like to add [envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) for auditing. So I have to register the Audit-Event-Listeners in my session factory. But in this case I have to use `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` instead `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. If I do so I have to switch from hibernate-xml based to annotation based mapping. Is there a way to add envers annotation in my existing hibernate-xml based mapping project?

Comment: Envers only works with annotations. So to be able to use envers you also have to move to annotations.

Comment: Is there any alternetive for envers?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781057/how-to-put-envers-annotations-into-xml-mapping-metadataorm-xml-file (which contains a reference to an issue which covers xml but still is open for years). You will have to use another solution something like [JaVers](http://javers.org) for instance.